# How to call any model function from common helper in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

if( !function_exists('audit') ) {
        function addAudit($id_user,$description)
        {

```
        $response_audit = $CI->Audit_model->addAudit($id_user,$description);
        if($response_audit){
            log_message('debug',' Product --addAudit :: Response received from model'); 
            }else{
            log_message('debug',' Product --addAudit :: Response didnot received from model'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also included
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('Audit_model');

At the top of helper

Comment: Actually, what you did is right way. What's the issue there?

Comment: Its giving error as 
Message: Undefined variable: CI

Filename: helpers/common_helper.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if( !function_exists('audit') ) { 
    function addAudit($id_user,$description) {
                $CI = &get_instance();
                $CI->load->model ( 'Audit_model' );
                $response_audit = $CI->Audit_model->addAudit($id_user,$description);
                if($response_audit){
                    log_message('debug',' Product --addAudit :: Response received from model'); 
                    }else{
                    log_message('debug',' Product --addAudit :: Response didnot received from model'); 
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of common helper:

```
public function __construct() {
    // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
}

//Now for loading a model
public function addAudit($id_user,$description){
    $this->CI->load->model('your_model_name');
    $response_audit =  $this->CI->your_model_name->addAudit($id_user,$description);
            if($response_audit){
                log_message('debug',' Product --addAudit :: Response received from model'); 
                }else{
                log_message('debug',' Product --addAudit :: Response didnot received from model'); 
            }
}
```